# Generic Execution of Stored Procedure in CSharp

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, computer-science

I am creating a generic library to execute stored procedures. Different stored procedures could have different number of input parameters.

Return type is always a table.

Using ADO.NET or Dapper, I can execute an SP with parameters, but how to make it generic to execute any SP that takes input parameters and returns a table result.

Thanks

Comment: Make a method that takes in a string param and a dictionary (of string, string) param, then iterate over the dictionary in your method to pull out param names and values.  The string param can be the name of your SP.  Just an idea!

Comment: Instead of a dictionary of strings I would suggest a generic list of sql parameters. That way it can be datatype independent and not force everything to string.

Comment: Agreed, just have to feed every parameter to the SP each time (i.e. can't take advantage of defaults/optional parameters).  Just a design consideration :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public DataTable RunSP_ReturnDT(string procedureName, List<SqlParameter> parameters, string connectionString)
    {
        DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConn))
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                }
                using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
                {
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtData);
                }
            }
        }
        return dtData;
    }
```